# find in a vector of enum

Tags: c++, vector, enums

I'm trying to find a enum item in a vector, Seems like some == operator issue. Any guidance please?

Here is the enum

```
enum RESPONSE{
 GAME_START='P',
 GAME_HELP='H',
 GAME_QUIT='Q'
}
```

Here is the usage

```
std::string s = getinputChar(); //this returns a string with a one character.

std::vector<RESPONSE> responces;
responces.push_back(GAME_START);
responces.push_back(GAME_QUIT);

std::vector<RESPONSE>::iterator it = find (responces.begin(), responces.end(), s.c_str());
```

Error:

`error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'RESPONSE' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Each enum is a `RESPONSE`.  Which will promote to an `int` if used in a context where a `RESPONSE` isn't acceptable.

Comment: @JamesKanze pretty right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c_str()` returns a `const char *` but your vector contains an enum. Did you want to compare the first character? Try `find(responces.begin(), responces.end(), static_cast<RESPONSE>(s[0]))`. This will stop working if you add an enum with a value larger than char

Comment: All answers working. But this is the one I was expected.

Comment: It will also stop working if the key character is preceded by white space, or if the string is empty.

Comment: @JamesKanze I am trusting his documentation `//this returns a string with a one character.` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could accept their input as `char` instead of `string`

```
char s = getinputChar();
```

Then you can change your `find` to

```
std::vector<RESPONSE>::iterator it = find (responces.begin(), responces.end(), static_cast<RESPONSE>(s));
```

Comment: This looks like the best answer to me.  If a function is called `getInputChar`, it should return a `char`, not an `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RESPONSE r = (RESPONSE) s[0]; // conversion from input string to RESPONSE
std::vector<RESPONSE>::iterator it = find (responces.begin(), responces.end(), r);
```

Comment: You should use `s[0]` as it's simpler and the compiler may add a bounds check.